# how to retrieve latest data from mysql table out of duplicate records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-performance, groupwise-maximum

I am trying to retrieve latest data from my sql table for each record. There will be duplicate data for each record with some data changes. I need to retrieve the latest timestamped data. Can someone suggest which is the optimum solution in terms of performance. Have seen some solutions with inner joins and sub queries.

Sample data given below

```
Technology Students Amount Area      Date
python     500      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 12:03:26
Ruby       100      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 05:18:50
Java       300      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 18:23:40
python     900      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 16:23:30
Java       100      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 12:23:50
Ruby       500      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 15:13:40
```

my o/p should contain latest data for each tech

```
Technology Students Amount Area      Date
Java       300      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 18:23:40
python     900      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 16:23:30
Ruby       500      1000   Bangalore 2021-08-06 15:13:40
```

Comment: please share the version of mysql you are using.

Comment: 5.6 is the version

Comment: Is thia a question of how to obtain the desired results or one about performance of solutions you haven't shared?

Comment: am actually looking for performance oriented solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One way to do this:-**
*Replace Table with real table Name.

```
select table.* 
from table
join 
(
    select Technology, max(Date) as max_dt 
    from table
    group by Technology
) t
on table.Technology= t.Technology and table.Date = t.max_dt
```

Comment: I was writing the same query and you posted before me. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for edit its body though, Now query looks more presentable. Appreciate that mate.

Comment: Thanks Amit and Jatin for your help. I wonder if there is any other way that I don't need to read the table twice in my query

Comment: Yes there is, however not in your older version of MySql - time to upgrade ;-)

Comment: can you please share the solution also the version  in which the solution is available

Answer (score 1):

The most performant solution where you don't need to self-join is to use a `window function`, optionally with a `cte` although a sub-query is fine also.

Unfortunately `row_number()` is supported only from version 8.0, however including here for completeness and to show why you should upgrade!

```
    with latest as (
        select * , Row_Number() over(partition by technology order by date desc) rn
        from t
    )
    select Technology, Students, Amount, Area, Date
    from latest
    where rn=1
```